# 3 sum implementation in python 2.7

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Working on below problem, looking for advice on code style, functional bug and time complexity improvements.

Also looking for advice in,

1. If array is not sorted, any solutions available for O(n^2) time complexity?
2. In my loop, I always search from `exclude_index + 1` to reduce duplicate, is it a safe start boundary?

**Problem**,

Given a sorted array and a target number, tell whether there are three numbers in the array which add up to the target number. (Time complexity should be O(n^2))

**Source code**,

```
def two_sum(numbers, start, end, target, exclude_index):
    while start < end:
        if start == exclude_index:
            start += 1
        elif end == exclude_index:
            end -= 1
        elif numbers[start] + numbers[end] > target:
            end -= 1
        elif numbers[start] + numbers[end] == target:
            print numbers[start], numbers[end], numbers[exclude_index]
            start += 1
            end -= 1
            while start < end and (numbers[start] == numbers[start - 1] or start == exclude_index):
                start += 1
            while start < end and (numbers[end] == numbers[end + 1] or end == exclude_index):
                end -= 1
        else:
            start += 1
def three_sum(numbers, target):
    for exclude_index in range(len(numbers)):
        if exclude_index > 0 and numbers[exclude_index] == numbers[exclude_index - 1]:
            continue
        two_sum(numbers, exclude_index + 1, len(numbers) - 1, target - numbers[exclude_index], exclude_index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12]
    three_sum(numbers, 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

As with most of your questions, your code violates [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

1. Don't `print` your output.
2. Since \$\text{start} = \text{exclude_index} + 1\$ you can never visit `exclude_index`.

Your code with the above changes make your code more readable.
But it'd be better if you:

1. Start using Python's standard library. [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) can drastically improve your codes readability.
2. Stop relying on `while` so much.
3. Use a dictionary, it's fast, and increases readability.
4. [`sorted` runs in \$O(n\log(n))\$ time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Using [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) you can generate all three of your numbers, still in \$O(n^2)\$ time.

1. Pass a sorted list to `combinations_with_replacement`, and generate two numbers.
2. Check `target - i - j` is in the list of numbers, and that it is greater or equal to `i` and `j`.
3. Group; `i`, `j` and `k`, in a `Counter` and check there is enough of each number in the original list.

```
import collections
import itertools

def three_sum(numbers, target):
    Counter = collections.Counter
    count = Counter(numbers)
    for i, j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list(sorted(count)), 2):
        k = target - i - j
        if k in count and j <= k >= i:
            nums = (i, j, k)
            if all(count[k] >= v for k, v in Counter(nums).items()):
                yield nums
```

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz, appreciate you pointed out so many areas for improvements and vote up. There is only one thing I do not quite agree, which is if you enumerate all 3 number combinations, time complexity is `O(n^2)` which is less than mine (which is `O(n*lgn)`)?

Comment: BTW, another thing I am confused is, why you are using `combinations_with_replacement ` other than `itertools.combinations`, I think `combinations_with_replacement ` considers repeated elements, but `list(sorted(count))` should be unique which is `dict` keys?

Comment: @LinMa Both mine and yours are \$O(n^2)\$. Try the code without `combinations_with_replacement`, and you'll see it doesn't work in all cases, such as ones that have duplicate values.